# JNI error when trying to access the EXTRA_ADDRESS_BOOK_INDEX field

Tags: java, android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I am trying to access the [`EXTRA_ADDRESS_BOOK_INDEX`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Data#extra_address_book_index) constant using JNI:

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL JNI_OnLoad(JavaVM* vm, void* reserved) {
    JNIEnv* env = nullptr;
    vm->GetEnv(reinterpret_cast<void**>(&env), JNI_VERSION_1_6);
    jclass clazz = env->FindClass("android/provider/ContactsContract$Data");
    jfieldID fieldID = env->GetStaticFieldID(clazz, "EXTRA_ADDRESS_BOOK_INDEX", "Ljava/lang/String;");
    jobject field = env->GetStaticObjectField(clazz, fieldID);
}
```

The `GetStaticObjectField` method crashes with an error:

> java_vm_ext.cc:534] JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: static jfieldID
>   0x6fd191b0 not valid for class
>   java.lang.Class<android.provider.ContactsContract$Data>

On the other hand if I try to access the [`VISIBLE_CONTACTS_ONLY`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Data#visible_contacts_only) field on the same class, everything works as expected:

```
jfieldID fieldID = env->GetStaticFieldID(clazz, "VISIBLE_CONTACTS_ONLY", "Ljava/lang/String;");
```

Any clues what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: What is the api level do you use?

Comment: I am testing this on an x86 Android Emulator API Level 27 (Android 8.1 - Google APIs). Also tested on Genymotion Emulators: API 21, API 23 and real Nexus 5 Device: API 23

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I tried to solve it and getting the same error, then I searched the source code of the final class [ContactsContract](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/provider/ContactsContract.java) and found that the field `EXTRA_ADDRESS_BOOK_INDEX` is not declared in the nested class **Data** but in a nested interface called **ContactCounts**.

So the solution is to replace `"android/provider/ContactsContract$Data"` by `"android/provider/ContactsContract$ContactCounts"`